# Returning from a long function on the first false condition

Tags: c, coding-style

I have a long(ish) function of the following pattern:

```
bool func(some_type_t *p1, another_t *p2)
{
  bool a = false, b = false, c = false, etc = false;

  a = (some_long && expression && \
       (that_deserves | its_own_line));

  b = (another || long_expression && \
       (that_deserves | its_own_line));

  c = and_so && on;

  return a && b && c && etc;
}
```

As you can see, the return value is `true` if and only if all flags are true. Hence I can return as soon as one of them turns out to be `false`. It may or may not be more optimal than the current version, but I want to do it to satisfy my [OCPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_personality_disorder). I thought of putting everything in a `do{}while(0);` and breaking out on `false`, but that looks odd (and I remember seeing something like that in tdwtf).

I do not want multiple return statements or deeply nested if blocks, and I certainly don't want to compromise on readability with a huge if that relies on short circuiting. I can live with `goto` in this case, but I want to know if there are any other patterns/constructs used in similar scenarios.

Comment: Just make it readable. The compiler will do the rest. What is wrong with multiple return statements? I use them all the time. You also should not have very long expressions as a general rule. If you do, then you are doing something wrong - break things out into smaller functions. Don't worry, the compiler will inline things if it can.

Comment: You get credit for remembering the TDWTF entry/entries(?) and not following their example :) What's wrong with multiple return statements?

Comment: I try to avoid multiple returns as a rule of thumb as they sometimes (not necessarily here) make it hard to debug. If you have just one return statement, you can put a print at the end of the function and see what it returns.

Comment: If it's C++, you create a log object which logs a message when it goes out of scope, so you don't need to add any explicit print statments.

Comment: There's a SE site for code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: How do you feel about the `?:` operator?

Comment: @Frustrated - yes, but code style questions are also on topic for us.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about multiple return statements. You can set up multiple breakpoints in the functions to trap where it returns. If you have 10 returns in a function, it's probably too long anyway.

Comment: Long expressions are *much* more of a readability problem than multiple return statements. They're also much harder to debug (you can't set a breakpoint in the middle of an expression). I try to avoid using the value of an assignment operation too, again because it decreases clarity…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I am overusing design patterns or something, but I would write this as

```
bool func(some_type_t *p1, another_t *p2) {

    return ( descriptive_name_for_a(p1,p2) &&
             descriptive_name_for_b(p1) &&
             etc );
}

bool descriptive_name_for_a(...) {
    return (some_long && expression && \
        (that_deserves | its_own_line));
}

//etc
```

}

This way people don't have to read the details of the long expressions if they just want to know what func does.

Comment: +1 This seems nice in general, but this is a comparison function and doesn't really qualify to be broken down further. I guess I will stick with `if(!a)goto EXIT;` pattern.

Answer (score 8):

Why not:

```
return
     (long expression a)
     && (long expression b)
     && (long expression c)
     && (etc.)
```

This will return as soon as it finds the first false value, thanks to the laziness of &&.

Comment: Debugging it may be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I like @Brad's idea about breaking up into functions, but if I couldn't I'd use multiple returns like so.  I haven't written C in about 10 years, so this is sorta C# pseudo-code...

**Edit:** To take into account @Frits' comments; with no attempt to apply DeMorgan's Law...

```
    bool func(T1 t1, T2)
    {            
        if(!(someLong && expression && (thatDeservers | itsOwnLine)))
            return false;
        if(!(another || longExpression && (thatDeservers | itsOwnLine)))
            return false;
        if(!(andSo && on)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Except, of course, that `a &&` clause is redundant if you only evaluate the expression if `a` is `true`. Ditto for `b &&`. And the intermediate returns can probably just return `false`. Finally, if after this the variables have only one use then you can even just put the whole expression in the `if()` and get rid of them entirely.

Comment: OP specifically says: `I do not want multiple return statements`

Comment: @Frits - Good catch. That's what you get when you throw together code with no forethought.  :)

Comment: @Frustrated - I'm aware of that.  I am firmly against that philosophy.  A single exit point almost always clutters the code, IMO.  Unfortunately, my hastily thrown together example doesn't illustrate the benefit of multiple returns.

Comment: @John Kraft: I think we're going to have to agree to disagree on that point (about single vs. multiple returns). ;)

Comment: Agreed @John Kraft.  The 'no multiple returns' thing usually leads to extra code complexity -- the reader of the code has to keep oodles of indentation levels straight in his head.  Returning as soon as you know you can return is simple, unambiguous, and highly informative.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C dev, but I typically format this with indentations and line continues to be a single statement with the short circuiting evaluator.  Rough guess in C it might look like:

```
bool func(some_type_t *p1, another_t *p2)
{
  return ((some_long && expression && (that_deserves | its_own_line))) && \
         ((another || long_expression && (that_deserves | its_own_line))) && \
         (and_so && on);
}
```

To my eye that is a lot more readable anyway.

If the blocks were really intolerably large I would do sub-blocks

```
bool func(some_type_t *p1, another_t *p2)
{
  return ((some_long && \
              expression && \ 
              (that_deserves | its_own_line))) && \
         ((another || long_expression && \ 
              (that_deserves | its_own_line))) && \
         (and_so && on);
}
```

But maybe I have spent too much time looking at lambda expressions...

Comment: No backslashes needed in C expressions (unless they're in a macro definition).

Answer (score 1):

Use this form using redundant checks as optimization:

```
bool func(some_type_t *p1, another_t *p2) {
    bool a = false, b = false, c = false;

    a = (some_long && expression && \
        (that_deserves | its_own_line));

    b = a && (another || long_expression && \
        (that_deserves | its_own_line));

    c = b && and_so && on;

    return c;
}
```

Here, each expression is guarded by a previous one, so there's just a negligible runtime overhead, no matter how long the complicated expression take, since none of them get evaluated needlessly. Most probably, the compiler can eliminate the overhead completely.

That said, I'd prefer multiple return statements, as they're much clearer and less error-prone, IMHO. For example, they allow you to reorder the parts easily.

Comment: I would usually go with multiple returns, but if not I think this is a great alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> I certainly don't want to compromise on readability with a huge if that relies on short circuiting.

Huh? I think having one conditional that relies on short circuiting is as clear and readable as possible.

Actually, even without the "if".

Just

```
return(a < 2 ? b :
       c < 3 ? d :
               e);
```

as the only line in the function.
Almost looks like normal mathematics.

Having multiple statements that look as if they are independent of each other but that really aren't independent at all is unreadable to my eyes (i.e. conditional gotos, temporary bool variables).

But of course it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: +1, but the last sentence is bad - it's a dementi of your former, reasonable statement.

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
#define BREAK_ON_FALSE(x) do { if (!(x)) goto leave_function; } while (0)

void your_function() {
    BREAK_ON_FALSE(first && condition && etc);
    BREAK_ON_FALSE(second && condition && etc);

    /* So on ... */
    return true;
leave_function:
    return false;
}
```

Comment: goto and #define in one function!

Comment: and `return false` in a void function.

Comment: I don't like the #define here, but the `goto` seems appropriate if any sort of cleanup might be necessary, or if the debugger would otherwise be unable to conveniently trap the early-exit case.